# https and ssh access to OpenVPN from windows

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn

I recently installed OpenVPN on a remote CentOS 7 web server.  I am able to connect to it from a local CentOS 7 devbox by typing `openvpn --config /path/to/client.ovpn`.  Once the connection is made, I am then able to `ssh` to the server through the vpn by typing `ssh username@10.8.0.1`, and I am able to view web apps hosted by apache on the remote server through the vpn by typing `https : / / 10.8.0.1` into a web browser.  **So how can I my non-technical end-users make the same https connections from windows?**

I downloaded and installed the [SecurePoint OpenVPN client for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/securepoint/).  I was then able to create a config for the server, including links to the .crt and .key files and definitions of other parameters that were defined in the `client.ovpn` file in Linux.  The SecurePoint client then forced me to use a username and password for an OS account on the remote server (perhaps for the better), but does not allow me to connect to web apps running on the server.  Specifically, typing `https : / / 10.8.0.1` into a web browser results in "This page can't be displayed", even though my Linux devbox allows content to be served from the server through the vpn to the client as described in the preceding paragraph.  **What am I doing wrong?  And how can I get this to work?**

**EDIT**

As per @garethTheRed's advice, I typed `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=internal` and got the following results:

```
internal (active)
  interfaces: tun0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client https ipp-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source NOT address="10.8.1.1" service name="ssh" reject
```

I then clicked "connect" in the SecurePoint GUI and, after it said the connection to the server was established, I opened up cmd.exe and typed `ping 10.8.0.1` and got the following results:

```
Pinging 10.8.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.8.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Unchecking the user/auth option removed the username/password login requirement.

Note that, when SecurePoint is connected, all other internet access through the browser seems blocked because all requests for pages are rejected.  Also, the VPN shows up in the windows list of wifi networks as "Unidentified Network" with "no internet access".  When I disconnect from the VPN using SecurePoint, the "Unidentified Network" goes away.  You can see what it looks like when the VPN connection is active [by clicking on this link](http://postimg.org/image/j5benplvh/)

**What else can I try?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that your firewall on the CentOS server (`internal` zone if that where the `tun0` device is located) has `https` available as a service.

You should be able to ping the server on `10.8.0.1` from the Windows machine.  If this works, then your VPN is up and working and it's probably the CentOS server's firewall blocking you.

If the ping doesn't work, then you have deeper underlying problems to solve before you look into your `https` pages.

In the case of the latter, post the output of running `ìpconfig /all` and `route print` on the Windows machine.

**Official OpenVPN Client**

As an experiment, you could also install `openvpn` on the Windows machine and run it in a similar way to the way you did on the CentOS client using similar configuration files. It may give a clue to what's happening:

Download the OpenVPN client for Windows from [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html), then install it. Towards the end of the installation you should see a tick-box that offers to start the client.  Make sure that the client is NOT started.

Copy your `*.ovpn` file from the CentOS machine (the one that worked previously) to the Windows machine. If you are transferring the file, you may come across the issue of Unix/DOS line terminators. The `dos2unix` package has a converter called `unix2dos` that converts the files to DOS format for you.

Open `notepad` as Administrator (right click and choose "Run as administrator") and edit the `*.ovpn` file  changing the paths to the key and two certificates remembering to use two back-slashes in the paths (e.g. `C:\\Users\\Bloggs\\key.pem`). Save this file to `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config`.

Start the OpenVPN client from the Start Menu by right clicking on it and choosing "Run as administrator" (this is only needed the first time you run it). If the above has worked you should be able to right click on the icon in the task-bar and connect.  If there is no connect option, then check the above.

After a second or three, you'll get a pop-up telling you that you've connected.  Try your `https` webpage.

**Basic Windows Compatible Configuration**

As a test, backup your current server configuration and try the following:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/pki/openvpn/cacerts/CA.crt
cert /etc/pki/openvpn/public/OpenVPN_Server.crt
key /etc/pki/openvpn/private/OpenVPN_Server.pem  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/pki/openvpn/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

It works on my server with both Linux and Windows clients (both the OpenVPN and the SecurePoint) one.  It won't provide the functionality you need for your server, but it may help you find where the problem is. You may need to adjust the paths to the files, of course.

For reference, here is the `*.ovpn` file I used:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <IP or FQDN of server> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
ca C:\\Users\\gareth\\ca.crt
cert C:\\Users\\gareth\\client.pem
key C:\\Users\\gareth\\key.crt
```

For the SecurePoint client, I left everything as default other than the `Auth user/pass` tick-box, which I un-ticked and (of course) the key and certificates.

Comment: Thank you.  I did download and run `openvpn-install-2.3.6-I601-x86_64` to install OpenVPN on windows, but I could not get cmd.exe to accept `openvpn --config C:\\path\\to\\administrators.ovpn`, so I stopped.  Is there a better way to install and run OpenVPN?  Also, I just posted the results of `ipconfig /all` and `route print` at a file sharing site.  Does this help you see my problem?  Here is the link: https://jumpshare.com/v/iSCbXFPeWOE2LBCmKT6l?b=qDw2tpNNsXQdiwl3Tili

Comment: Thank you.  I just connected the VPN and ran the two commands.  Note that I had to then disconnect the vpn again afterwards before being able to connect to this or any other web site again after running the two commands.  Here is the link to the output of the two commands when connected to the VPN: https://jumpshare.com/v/ncKtK9dYFVueATXpCFBZ?b=qP8Bi0TKuqPaUgXAFcfL

Comment: I backed up the old `server.conf` then used your new `server.conf` and typed `sudo systemctl stop openvpn@server.service` and `sudo systemctl start openvpn@server.service`, but it is giving me EXTREMELY inconsistent results. At times, it lets me successfully `https : / 10.8.0.?` from windows but at other times it does not.  When I place `route 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0` and `client-config-dir ccd` into the new `server.conf` then restart openvpn, SecurePoint logs me in as 10.8.1.1 so that I can ssh, but then I cannot https anymore. When I delete those lines and restart, I still cannot https

Comment: When I switch to my CentOS 7 devbox and try to login to the vpn using `openvpn --config /path/to/administrators.ovpn`, it first runs through its sequence before printing `Initialization Sequence Complete`, but then it continues to print out the following again and again: `Sun Feb 22 14:15:56 2015 Bad LZO decompression header byte: 42`, and I am not able to https or ssh.  What else can I try?

Comment: Lzo compression must be enabled or disabled in the config at BOTH ends.

Comment: I can log out of windows and go back to CentOS to check that...but will that affect the windows problem that is initiating this post?

Comment: `comp-lzo` is in `administrators.ovpn`, but SecurePoint does not use that file.

Comment: Given that your server.conf works for you with windows and Linux clients, can you share the SecurePoint configuration that works with it and also the ovpn? It is not yet working for me.

Comment: @CodeMed - done :-) The TZ difference doesn't help us resolve this quickly!

Comment: I figured out the problem. I do have `ssh` and `https` enabled in the internal zone of firewalld, but the problem came when they were not also enabled in the public zone as well. I can re-create the problem by turning these services off in the public zone, then solve the problem again by turning them back on in the public zone. This makes no sense to me because I thought these services were running through port 1192 as OpenVPN. Do I have other options besides leaving these services open in the public zone and adding rich rules to block ip addresses outside the vpn? +1 for getting me this far

Comment: I've just removed `http` from my external zone and I can still access `http://10.8.0.1`, which is what's expected.  I'd double check your whole firewalld configuration to start with.

Comment: Thank you.  I am marking this question as answered because it seems the firewall question is a separate item.  Are you willing to help me with that as well?  I so very much appreciate your guidance.  Note that the new question is framed by things I have learned from you already.  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186441/firewalld-settings-for-openvpn-with-https-ssh-and-smtp